# CSS3 transitions: disable reverting animation

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm setting this style to show animation when element height changes **from 0 to 30**:

```
.information-bar { height: 30px; }
.information-bar-collapsed { height: 0; }
.information-bar { background-color: #f9e288; -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease; -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease; }
```

But it also show animation when element height changes **from 30 to 0**. How can I avoid the second animation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding this style:

```
.information-bar-collapsed { -moz-transition: all 0s ease; -webkit-transition: all 0s ease; }
```

Now when information bar shows it shows with animation, and when it hides animation does not show.